# How to load an image from images directory in GPU module?

Tags: python, gpu

How can I load an image from an images directory in `GPU` module?

From https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html#d-image

```py
import bpy
import gpu
import bgl
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

IMAGE_NAME = "Untitled"
image = bpy.data.images[IMAGE_NAME]

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_IMAGE')
batch = batch_for_shader(
    shader, 'TRI_FAN',
    {
        "pos": ((100, 100), (200, 100), (200, 200), (100, 200)),
        "texCoord": ((0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)),
    },
)

if image.gl_load():
    raise Exception()


def draw():
    bgl.glActiveTexture(bgl.GL_TEXTURE0)
    bgl.glBindTexture(bgl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, image.bindcode)

    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_int("image", 0)
    batch.draw(shader)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`BlendDataImages.load()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataImages.html?highlight=load#bpy.types.BlendDataImages.load) to *load* and *assign* the image in one go:

```
>>> image = D.images.load("//textures/your_image.exr")
>>> image
bpy.data.images['your_image.exr']
```

Following demo is based on the [given link to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html#d-image):

[image]

```
import bpy
import gpu
import bgl
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

image = bpy.data.images.load("//textures/your_image.exr")

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_IMAGE')
batch = batch_for_shader(
    shader, 'TRI_FAN',
    {
        "pos": ((100, 100), (200, 100), (200, 200), (100, 200)),
        "texCoord": ((0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)),
    },
)

if image.gl_load():
    raise Exception()


def draw():
    bgl.glActiveTexture(bgl.GL_TEXTURE0)
    bgl.glBindTexture(bgl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, image.bindcode)

    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_int("image", 0)
    batch.draw(shader)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

---

**Modal Draw Operator**

Following demo is based on our famous *Operator Modal View 3D* template that comes with Blender. I'd suggest load the image before calling the actual draw method e.g. as part of `invoke` or `register` methods... or load it using another operator in the first place.

In order to avoid that Blender loads the same image from disc over and over again, you can pass `check_existing=True` to [`BlendDataImages.load()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataImages.html?highlight=load#bpy.types.BlendDataImages.load) or just get the image via `D.images.get("your_image.exr")` once loaded:

[image]

```
import bpy
import gpu
import bgl
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
import os.path


def draw_callback(self, context):
    shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_IMAGE')
    batch = batch_for_shader(
        shader, 'TRI_FAN',
        {
            "pos": ((100, 100), (600, 100), (600, 300), (100, 300)),
            "texCoord": ((0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)),
        },
    )
    image = self.image
    if image.gl_load():
        raise Exception()

    bgl.glActiveTexture(bgl.GL_TEXTURE0)
    bgl.glBindTexture(bgl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, image.bindcode)
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_int("image", 0)
    batch.draw(shader)


class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Draw a line with the mouse"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal View3D Operator"
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            # Remove the image from the data-blocks
            bpy.data.images.remove(self.image)
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'} # {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            
            # Load and assign the image
            self.image = bpy.data.images.load("//textures/your_image.exr", check_existing=True)
            # Or just get one from the data-blocks
            #self.image = bpy.data.images.get("your_image.exr")
            
            # Add the region OpenGL drawing callback
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback, (self, context), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Make sure the path to your image is correct *(line 44)*, run the script, press <kbd>F3</kbd> in 3d View, type "*Simple Modal View3D ...*" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to kill the image.